# Optimal OO Design for a Mixed Instrument Portfolio

Tags: oop, design-patterns, finance

I'm designing a system designed to calculate various metrics on a set of holdings based on an initial day's holding and a feed of new trades and price ticks. 
The initial information comes from a WCF service with events for new trades and price updates.

The metrics required include market value (MV) that also needs to be aggregated into a hierarchy in various ways.

On the initial load we get a set of objects which look like:

**Position** [ Qty:double, Security:Security, Account:Account, Strategy:Strategy ]

**Security** [ Price:Money, Country:Country, Currency:CCY ]

**Account** [ Name:string, Fund:Fund, Manager:Manager, Currency:CCY ]

**Strategy** [Name:string]

**Fund** [Name:string]

**Manager** [Name:string]

The multiplicity looks like this:

- Manager (1)  -manages-> (1..*) Account
- Fund (1)     -is made up of-> (1..*) Account
- Account (1)  -contains-> (1..*) Position
- Security (1) -can be in-> (1..*) Position
- Strategy (1) -contains-> (1..*) Position
- Strategy (1) -can exist in-> (1..*) Account

There are also a number of things that will happen during the day:

- Security price change - price of security changes from a -> b
- New position - There has been a trade
- Remove position - A trade has been cancelled

From the front end - we need to be able to view the data on a Manager/Fund level i.e.

- Manager 1

  - Total MV = $4800
  - Biggest country exposure = 43% UK
  - Total % MV = 100%
  - Components : List>
  - Countries : List>
- Manager 2

  - Total MV = $1200
  - Biggest country exposure = 90% USA
  - Total % MV = 100%
  - Components : List>
  - Countries : List>
- Fund2

  - Total MV = $1200
  - Biggest country exposure = 90% USA
  - Total % MV = 100%
  - Components : List>
  - Countries : List>

Or at a security level

- Sec 1

  - MV = $1000
  - % of Manager 1 = 67%
  - % of Fund 1 = 48%
- Sec 2

  - MV = $2000
  - % of Manager 3 = 12%
  - % of Fund 2 = 4%
    ...

Entities will be loading in an identity map to ensure they exist only once in the system and so a change to a security's price will be reflected in the relevant positions.

I've look at various way's to represent this, conceptually event sourcing (http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) looked promising although we only need to look at the current state so is probably overkill.

My current line of thinking is to represent *Manager*, *Fund* and *Account* as **Portfolio** object:

And to use the composite pattern (Portfolio : Component, Position : Component)  + visitor patterns to encapsulate hierarchy + calculation logic respectively.

**Portfolio** [ object: Represents, Components: ListOfComponents, Accept(Visitor v) : state ]

Component also has MV (in $) (these can be calculated using a visitor)

Let MV [position] = *Qty * Security.Price*

Let MV [portfolio] = sum of all MV of positions below.

So we have the following composite structure:

- Portfolio (Represents: Fund A, MV: **500**)

  - Portfolio (Represents: Account A, MV: **500**)

    - Position1 (MV: 300)
    - Position2 (MV: 200)
- Portfolio (Represents: Fund B, MV **1600**)

  - Portfolio (Represents: Account B, MV: **1000**)

    - Position3 (MV: 800)
    - Position4 (MV: 200)
  - Portfolio (Represents: Account C, MV: **600**)

    - Position5 (MV: 200)
    - Position6 (MV: 400)

My first problem is with the representation of various levels of percentage - the system needs to be able to represent what percentage of Fund B and Account C does Position 5 make up?

Position 5 MV / Account C MV = 200 / 600 = 33%

Position 5 MV / Fund B MV = 200 / 1600 = 12.5%

The values can be calculated using the visitor but where do we store the results of the calculation?

In a dictionary in the *Position 5* like so:
Dictionary percentMV = {[Fund B, 12.5%], [Account C, 33%]}

Or in the relevant portfolios in which case, all of the individual positions would need to be referenced by Fund B? **We would also need Position 5 in terms of the Manager that manages it.**

The other concept I'm having difficulty with is country exposure metric - each security represents a certain amount of risk associated with a country. 
So with a portfolio of two positions:
 - MV of $100, Security Country = UK
 - MV of $300, Country = USA

The portfolio has a Country exposure of - 100/400 =25% UK, and 300/400 = 75% USA.

What's the best way to generalize this concept into the design i.e. where's the best place store the data?

Comment: +1 Very good, detailed question. Just please don't store your prices as doubles; use decimals.

Answer (score 1):

The *Portfolio* is a good idea to represent arbitrary segmentations of a population of positions; be sure to also take a look at the [*Specification* pattern (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) for a generic way to specify the inclusion criteria for the portfolios. In fact, the *portfolio* pattern described in *Analysis Patterns* (Martin Fowler) is compared to the 
*Specification* pattern described in *Domain Driven Design* (Eric Evans).

Now, a *Portfolio* just represents an inclusion criteria of positions. To actually aggregate the positions in different ways, take a look at the *Enterprise Segment* pattern (described in *Analysis Patterns*). An *Enterprise Segment* is a slice of the different *dimension elements* that comprise your domain (in your case: security, manager and fund) on which interesting *measurements* can be aggregated, calculated and stored (like market value and country exposure).

Also, be sure to take a look at more fundamental patterns like *Money*, *Quantity* and *Range*; and always use *decimals* or *integers* to store monetary values or rates for monetary calculations.

Comment: I've ordered a copy of Pattern Analysis - I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: By the way - if money is needed to the nearest whole - wouldn't it be faster to use double instead of decimal?

Comment: do you have any examples of the enterprise segment in use? I'm finding it difficult to map the pattern onto the problem

Comment: @James: I'm sorry but I don't have an example. I'll try to come up with one later if I find some time...